# Каким образом организовать хранение данных?

Tags: база-данных

Возник вопрос касающийся организации хранилища разнообразного вида информации,
начиная от текстовых документов и просто текста и заканчивая небольшими видеофайлами.

Хранение текста не проблема в БД, но если хранить в ней изображения то, она начинает очень быстро расти в размерах, а этого не хотелось бы.
Хранение в каталогах конечно тоже ничего, но слишком неудобен перенос информации с ПК на ПК, одним файлом как то удобнее.

Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с подобными проблемами поделитесь пожалуйста своим опытом в их решении.

Comment: ничего необычного в хранении картинок, видео и тому подобного "тяжелого" контента в БД нет, для этого даже придумали специльный тип данных - blob. Расти в размерах она будет примерно с той же скоростью, что и папка с файлами.

Comment: те. ни чего такого, что я буду хранить все данные программы в БД? ну понятно, что где необходимо использовать blob поля

Comment: @NMD, ну по-хорошему этот вопрос должен решаться после составления ТЗ. Разграничение доступа, хитрый поиск по содержимому (хз, возможно ли вообще такое) - файлы хранятся в БД. Максимальная скорость, доступ к файлам без программы, произвольный движок БД - файлы хранятся вне БД. Ни то, ни се - по личному предпочтению. Если программу делаете только для себя, то можете ради опыта поработать с блобами. А можете оформить все в класс HitryDataProvider и реализовать сразу оба способа, а конкретный выбирать через конфиг.

Comment: все зависит от того какая нагрузка планируется на ваш сервер (варианты по возрастанию нагрузки на примере веб-ресурса):  

1) веб сервер и субд крутятся на одном сервере (вариант размещения медиа данных в субд я даже не рассматриваю).  
2) веб сервер и субд крутятся на разных серверах  
3) веб сервер и субд крутятся на разных серверах + статику отдает еще 1 сервер (все статичные файлы: video, audio, html, css, etc...

... (здесь еще несколько других вариантов но врядли они вам понадобятся) ...

Comment: сервер СУБД и десктопная клиентская часть все на одном ПК.
однопользовательский режим работы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поделюсь своим мнением на этот счет. Хранить в базе на мой взгляд нужно только текстовую информацию (в основном из-за возможности организовать очень удобный и быстрый поиск по тексту) и ссылки на файлы и др. ресурсы. Если нужно как-то иметь доступ из БД к изображениям/видеороликам, то лучше просто закиньте путь в БД (ну можете еще какую-то информацию хранить, чтобы можно было организовать удобный поиск по вашей коллекции), а затем программно подгружайте их.

Answer (score 2):

База обычно самое узкое место в проекте. Поэтому на неё всегда стараются нагрузить как можно меньше работы, а Вы занимаетесь противоположным. Каждый должен заниматься своим делом) Можно и операции математические базе отдать, но зачем?)

Comment: так что посоветуете делать?

Comment: Судя по сообщению о переносе, предполагается обычная программа. Хотя я тоже сторонник хранить в БД только ссылки на файлы.

Comment: да вы правы. программа для личного использования.

Comment: Расскажите про объёмы данных. Как много планируется роликов (видео) и прочее.

Comment: куски исходников,
скрины разнообразные до 3мб,
архивы до 100мб,
видео до 100МБ,
аудио думаю макс 20мб